# NUnit : Effort.Exceptions.EffortException : The Effort library failed to register its provider automatically, so manual registration is required

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, nunit, effort

I am working on Web API and while unit testing using NUnit i faced this error which said:

```
Tests.DemoTest.SessionLogOnBreakdownTest:
SetUp : Effort.Exceptions.EffortException : The Effort library failed to register its provider automatically, so manual registration is required.

a) Call the Effort.Provider.EffortProviderConfiguration.RegisterProvider() method at entry point of the application

or

b) Add the following configuration to the App.config file:
   <system.data>
      <DbProviderFactories>
         <add name="Effort.Provider"
              invariant="Effort.Provider"
              description="Effort.Provider"
              type="Effort.Provider.EffortProviderFactory, Effort" />
      </DbProviderFactories>
   </system.data>
  ----> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException : Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider.
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Here is the Test which i am running:

```
[TestFixture]
public class DemoTest : TestBase
{
    private TestContext _context;
    private DbConnection _dbConnection;

    [SetUp]
    public void Initialization()
    {
        //Effort.Provider.EffortProviderConfiguration.RegisterProvider();
        _dbConnection = Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient();
        _context = new TestContext(_dbConnection);
    }

    [Test]
    public void SessionLogOnBreakdownTest()
    {
         //code which uses _context
    }
}
```

Error is thrown at `_dbConnection = Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient();`

I have followed both the suggestions which the exception gives. But none worked.

Things i have tried:

- Those two suggestions in the exception helper
- Update-Package -reinstall Effort

Comment: You can't have tried suggestion (a) unless you recompiled NUnit, which is the "application" in this case.

Comment: Suggestion (b) is your best bet. You have to change the config __for your tests__ not the App.config for your application. Your test config is something like my.test.assembly.config.

Answer (score 1):

I am also seeing this happen in a .Net 4.6.1 application using EF6 (6.4.0-6.4.4) and Effort.EF6 2.2.10.  I've tried a few different version combinations but seeing it happen at random via the test explorer in VS and nearly consistently via dotnet test.  Note I have tried A, B and A & B solutions proposed in the error msg.